# JS doesn't update variable value and outputs old result

Tags: javascript

I updated the value of the variable val1, but the value 5 is still displayed in the console.

```
let val1 = 2
let val2 = 3
let sum = val1 + val2
console.log(sum) // 5
val1 = 3
console.log(sum) // 5
```

After changing the value of val1, I expected to see the updated value of the sum equal to = 6. But its old value of the sum was displayed. Why hasn't the value been updated?

Comment: Because variables are not dynamic by default, it would be very annoying

Comment: Variables hold values. They're not aliases for the expression you assign to them.

Comment: Look up functions

Comment: Why do you think that `sum` should be updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are printing the sum which has been already taken the value. So if you really want to updated sum of value val1 you could write your code like this.

```js
let val1 = 2
let val2 = 3
let sum = val1 + val2
console.log(sum) // 5
val1 = 3
console.log(val1+val2) // 6
```

Comment: *"or use var"* – what do you mean by this?

Comment: daclare variable with var keyword. Which is updatable.

Comment: There's no difference between `let` and `var` in that regard.

Comment: I am updating my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function

```js
let val1 = 2
let val2 = 3
let sum = () => val1 + val2
console.log(sum()) // 5
val1 = 3
console.log(sum()) // 6
```

Comment: let sumArrowFunction = (a,b) => a + b; is more reusable but you're true.

Answer (score 0):

You change the values but you don't update the sum!

Method 1 :

```js
let val1 = 2
let val2 = 3
let sum = val1 + val2 // do the sum of the values
console.log(sum) // 5
val1 = 3
sum = val1 + val2 // redo the sum of the updated values
console.log(sum) // 6
// Or just
console.log(val1+val2) // 6
```

Method 2 :

```js
function sumFunction(a,b){
  return (a+b);
}
val1 = 2;
val2 = 3;
console.log(sumFunction(val1,val2)); //output 5
val1 = 3;
val2 = 3;
console.log(sumFunction(val1,val2)); //output 6
console.log(sumFunction(5,8)); // output 13
```

Method 2b :

```js
val1 = 2;
val2 = 3;
console.log(sumFunction(val1,val2)); //output 5
val1 = 3;
val2 = 3;
console.log(sumFunction(val1,val2)); //output 6
console.log(sumFunction(5,8)); // output 13
function sumFunction(a,b){
   return (a+b);
}
```

Method 3 (as Konrad suggest a function too):

```js
val1 = 4;
val2 = 5;
let sumArrowFunction = (a,b) => a + b;
console.log(sumArrowFunction(val1,val2));
console.log(sumArrowFunction(5,5));
```

Alternative method to be complete:
Here you display the full operation...

```js
val1 = 2;
val2 = 1;
console.log(calcFunction(val1,val2));
console.log(calcFunction(12,3));
function calcFunction(a,b){
   return (`${a}  + ${b}  =  ${a+b}`);
}
```

Comment: In the case of a named arrow function, you must call it after the function is declared.

Comment: The best way to learn such basics things is to read all the possibilities contained in one post.
Don't be afraid to read and try @Tesla Fake